# What is the C++ equivalent of this python code?

Tags: python, c++

`li = list(map(int,input().split()))`

I am pretty new to c++ . I essentialy want the easiest verison of this code which takes in the input I pass in via terminal and push back the output to a vector.

I've tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string input;
    vector<int> numbers;
    while(getline(cin,input,' ')){
        numbers.push_back(stoi(input));
    }
    for(int i : numbers){
        cout << i << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am using g++ 9.2.0.
The same code works fine on an online ide. I am not sure if it's an issue with the g++ compiler or not.
Weird Stuff!

Comment: Can you explain what that does for us non python people?

Comment: It takes in a list of numbers like "1 2 3 4 5" separated by blank spaces and appends the elements in a list. I want the same for c++. Just trying to learn here.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `string input;
    vector<int> numbers;
    while(getline(cin,input,' ')){
        numbers.push_back(stoi(input));
    }`

Comment: somehow the elements are not getting added to the vector .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example runs fine for me: https://ideone.com/bFLjB1

You could clean this up a bit by using the default type deduction and whitespace-splitting behavior of `cin`'s `operator>>`:

```
std::vector<int> numbers;
int temp = 0;
while (std::cin >> temp) {
    numbers.push_back(temp);
}
```

Comment: The same works for me in online IDE. But in Local it gets stuck after taking input.   `PS C:\Users\sapta\Desktop\Codes\Practice> cd "c:\Users\sapta\Desktop\Codes\Practice\" ; if ($?) { g++ testr.cpp -o testr } ; if ($?) { .\testr }
1 2 3 4

`       **No Outputs Produced**

Comment: Because that's not how you provide data to STDIN. It wouldn't work for executing your Python example either.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this?

Comment: As of now. I always do this ..and it works fine for python and cpp too. I guess the numbers are getting appended but there is a print issue. If you could look into the print issue that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a container directly from whitespace delimited input.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> numbers(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), {});

    for(int i : numbers){
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```